Any image to SVG on Inkscape CLI
I want to generate gcode over any image. First I need to convert the image to SVG type. I want to use inkscape for this. I will use jscut to generate gcode. I generated an SVG file with the command below, but when I try to get gcode from this SVG file via jscut, I get the error “image is not supported; try Inkscape's Object to Path command”.
The CLI command I used is as follows.
inkscape pxtest.jpg --export-type=svg --actions=object-to-path
While I was expecting it not to give an error on JSCut, I got the error I mentioned above.

There's a relevan answer here: Command-line bitmap tracing with inkscape. Of course you need to performe bitmap tracing, not object-to-path.
